# How to set Bootstrap data-container to particular ID

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I tried to make a Bootstrap popover. For that I have written the following code as per the Bootstrap guide.

I am using Bootstrap 3.1.0.

```
<input id="shelfLifeField" type="text" placeholder="Use-By" class="form-control first" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<div class='row'>this is just for text</div>"/>
```

It's working fine but the problem was `popover content` appending to `body`. I found in the Bootstrap documentation that I can control through the `data-container` attribute.

```
  data-container="#anotherDivId"
```

Actually I want to append the popover content to specific div ("anotherDivId") instead of appending to `body`.

I failed with my idea so can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

`data-container="#anotherDivId"` is right and should work.

Be careful though that if #anotherDivId is hidden (with display:none), then the popover won't work